# Latex pseudo code

Tags: pseudocode

I'm thinking to present some pseudocode in an article by using Latex, and ideally I would like to have something similar to what is shown in the figure below. I searched and tried out some packages, but couldn't replicate the figure very well... I would be very appreciated if someone could help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this template:

```
\title{AlgorithmTemplate}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\KwIn{Input}
\KwOut{Output}

\nl \bf Pass\;
    \caption{{\bf Algorithm} \label{Algorithm}}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please also consider reading up on [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)